# How can I store a PIN number in a encoded algorithm? PYTHON3

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I'm currently teaching myself how to code in Python3. I'm doing this by doing various exercises etc. Basically, I have a program where the user will log-in to the program by having a unique PIN number. In this task, I have been asked to extend my program by doing the following:

"Create an encoding algorithm that will store the PIN in a format that cannot be read by just looking t the file. Only by running the PIN attempt through the same algorithm can the match be found."

What exactly does this mean? As I'm new to Python, I'm not fully sure what is being asked. Could someone point me in the right way, and how I would approach this question?

Comment: What you want is a cryptographic hash function.
https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `hash`:

```
a = hash("1234") 
assert(hash("1234") == a)
```

The idea is that for each pin input you will get an output Wich you can store and compare with but is not the pin itself.

Comment: What does  this do? I'd also like some clarity on exactly what the question is asking too? 

Thanks for your response btw !

Comment: Unfortunately `hash(1234) == 1234`. Integers have to get quite large before their hashes are not just themselves.

Comment: @JaredGoguen yeah, I forget to add the string marks, I'm on a bus and it's not comfortable to work on the Android app xD

Comment: Just to explain a hash is a 'signature' of an input. There is a finite (but very high) number of hashes. The number is so high that we can consider that every input has a unique output. By this way, you can save a hash of a code. Then when you want to test it, if the hash of the new test is equal to the saved hash, there is a very very high chance that the entered is OK. The advantage of the hash is that you cannot go back execpt if you have a dictionnary hash => code. I hope it's clear enought :s

Answer (score 0):

You should hash the pin when user creates account and store the result. Then when user enters pin again to login, hash the entered pin, and compare the result with the stored result. If Both of them match, he has the right pin.

Use SHA256 for hashing. Do your research on how to use SHA256.

Do not use MD5 or SHA1. They are not secure anymore.

Here is my collection of excerpts from various articles over the internet. I use it as a reference for my self, but it could probably of help to you.

https://hnode.github.io/website/blog/guides/passwords.html

The link explores various ways of handling passwords: from plain-text to hash-stretching, and how hashes work.

Disclaimer: I don't own the content of the article. I collected it from various relevant articles and formatted the collection into one article.